# PHP mongoDB get filtered count from million records is working very slow

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using below PHP code to get count of total entries in MongoDB

```
$command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command(['count' => 'log_master', 'query' => $filter]);
    try {
        $cursor = $m->executeCommand('DB_name', $command);
    } catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    }

$count = $cursor->toArray()[0]->n;
```

it works fine but takes too much time if filters are on two or three fields. Records in table are around 50 millions. How I can speed up count query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you need to start indexing your data. Here are [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) and [a tutorial](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/mongodb-indexing-tutorial-with-example/). To see how your query is being executed you may employ [`explain()` method in shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).